# Show custom brand attribute in sidebar wishlist - magento 2

Tags: magento2

Can we show or display custom attribute like **brand** in sidebar wishlist? If yes then how?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, we can display custom attribute in sidebar wishlist item.

1. Override **wishlist.php** file into your module.

   `vendor/magento/module-wishlist/CustomerData/Wishlist.php` to

   `app/code/[Vendor_Name]/[Module_Name]/CustomerData/Wishlist.php`

   I added one custom **brand** attribute in this file.

   **Example:** *'product_brand' => $product->getAttributeText("brand"),*

   See screenshot

   [image]
2. Add or Edit **di.xml** file `app/code/[Vendor_Name]/[Module_Name]/etc/di.xml`

> `<?xml version="1.0"?> <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd"> <preference for="Magento\Wishlist\CustomerData\Wishlist" type="CsVikram\CustomAttribute\CustomerData\Wishlist" /> </config>`

3. Now you can get attribute value in **sidebar.phtml** template file. Please override this file in your theme from vendor. `vendor/magento/module-wishlist/view/frontend/templates/sidebar.phtml` to `app/design/frontend/[Vendor_Name]/[Theme_Name]/Magento_Wishlist/templates/sidebar.phtml`

   **Example:** `<div class="brand-name"><span data-bind="text: product_brand"></span></div>`

   [image]

   Please upgrade and clean cache. I hope it will work like my screenshot.